# Solution to not being able to add alias in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am aware that in SQL server one cannot use an alias as column name inside the WHERE clause. Although the filters in the WHERE I currently have do not seem to work, I have tried many times to filter files by extension (only LDF and MDF) but it doesn't work. Below is what I have, and I am wondering if anyone knows a way to achieve this.

All I want in my output set is rows with LDF or MDF in the FileType column.

Here is what I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        CWV.SystemName ,
        CIL.CIL_INSTANCE_NAME AS [Instance Name] ,
        CWV.DriveLetter ,
        UPPER(RIGHT(CIDFP.physical_name, 3)) AS FileType ,
        CIDFP.physical_name AS [Physical Name]
FROM    CCS_InstanceDatabaseFilesProperty AS CIDFP
        INNER JOIN CCS_INSTANCE_LIST AS CIL ON CIL.CIL_ID = CIDFP.CIL_ID
        INNER JOIN CCS_InstanceServerProperty AS CSP ON CSP.CIL_ID = CIDFP.CIL_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CCS_Win32_Volume AS CWV ON CIL.CSL_ID = CWV.CSL_ID
                                                   AND LEFT(CIDFP.physical_name,
                                                      2) = CWV.DriveLetter
WHERE   ( CWV.SystemName IS NOT NULL )
        AND ( CWV.DriveLetter IS NOT NULL )
        OR RIGHT(CIDFP.physical_name, 3) = 'mdf'
        OR RIGHT(CIDFP.physical_name, 3) = 'ldf'
```

Thanks in advance for any input/answers.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doesn't work" but you are missing some parenthesis in your predicates.

Comment: doesn't work meaning conditions in my where clause have are not affecting the result set the way I am expecting it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE   ( CWV.SystemName IS NOT NULL )
        AND ( CWV.DriveLetter IS NOT NULL )
        AND (RIGHT(CIDFP.physical_name, 3) = 'mdf'
        OR RIGHT(CIDFP.physical_name, 3) = 'ldf')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `AND`/`OR` logic is not grouped properly.

If you want DriveLetter is not null `AND` physical_name = 'mdf' `OR` 'ldf' you might change it like this:

```
WHERE   CWV.SystemName IS NOT NULL
    AND CWV.DriveLetter IS NOT NULL 
    AND RIGHT(CIDFP.physical_name, 3) in ('mdf', 'ldf')
```

Comment: This isn't working either. I have some rows that have the word "Catalog" and the RIGHT is making it show up as "LOG" along with the LDF's and MDF's. I am also seeing NDF's.